# How to properly format string for the setValue() function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to add the value `US punctuation + alphanumeric lowercase:[a-z0-9,.?;:!&()_'"]+` to a cell from my spreadsheet but I get the error:

> Missing ) after argument list.

How can I correct that string if it has `'` and `"` ?

This is my code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetConfig = ss.getSheetByName("Config");
sheetConfig.getRange("K18").setValue("US punctuation + alphanumeric lowercase:[a-z0-9,.?;:!&()_'"]+");
```

And this is what I've tried so far:

1.

```
sheetConfig.getRange("K18").setValue("US punctuation + alphanumeric lowercase:[a-z0-9,.?;:!&()_''' '"']+");
```

2.

```
sheetConfig.getRange("K18").setValue("US punctuation + alphanumeric lowercase:[a-z0-9,.?;:!&()_ ''"']+");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this would fix it:

```
sheetConfig.getRange("K18").setValue("US punctuation + alphanumeric lowercase:[a-z0-9,.?;:!&()_"+"'"+'"]+');
```